# Java:Beginner question: Why do I not get the numbers (1,4,9,16,25,36,49) from this code

Tags: java

I am currently doing some hyperskill education and I do not get why this code skips some numbers for no reason. The input from java Scanner is 50 so basically N=50

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // put your code here
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        int x = 1;
        int Square = x * x;

        while (x * x <= N) {
            Square = x * x;
            System.out.println(Square);
            x += x;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers I get are 1,4,and 16.

Comment: What what is wrong at 1,4 and 16? Take a paper and a pen and calculate on paper what your code do.

Comment: Turns out I had it all wrong. I thought x += x is not x +1 but x+x. I got it now ty for the advice

Comment: You are right `x += x` it's not `x+1`. `a += b` it's short for `a = a + b`. Also for `x += 1`, you can simply call `x++` or `++x`.  http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because... that's what the code does.

`x` is 1 in the first loop, meaningly, the square is `1*1`, which is 1.

Then, you add x to itself (`x += x`), so in the next cycle, x is 2, and the square is 4.

Then, you add x to itself again, and now x is 4, and the square of that is 16.

I have no idea why you were expecting to get 9 from this.

If you replace `x += x` with `x += 1` (or, shorter, `x++`), you'd get 1,4,9,16,25,36,49.

NB: In general, to know why code isn't working / doesn't do what you want, debug it. Invest some time in learning how to use a debugger, or if you just can't do that, debug inefficiently, using a lot of `System.out.println` statements. Walk through the code 'mentally', be the computer, figure out at each step what happens and what the values of variables will be, and then compare what you think happens to what actually happens (by checking the debugger, or, by printing the values of various variables). At the point where what you think happens doesn't match what actually happens? You found a bug. That would have gotten you there in this case.

Comment: omg x+= x is not x = x +1 but x=x+x? I had it all wrong :/ Thank you very much

Comment: The problem is that I sometimes use the computer at work to learn coding. So it is super slow that is why I didnt try the print method. But I will check debugger. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

```
 x += x;
```

Should be

```
 x += 1;
```

instead - so you get the next number. With x += x in place you get x as 1, 2, 4 and then 8... and 8x8 = 64 is outside your when condition :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that line;

`x += x;`

you add x to x, so you multiply x by 2;

```
1) x=1 -> x*x=1
2) x=2 -> x*x=4
2) x=4 -> x*x=16
2) x=8 -> x*x=64
```

You must add 1 to x.

So change this line `x += x;` by `x += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Putting in a few simple print statements might have shed some light.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// put your code here
int N = scanner.nextInt();
int x = 1;
int Square = x * x;

while (x * x <= N) {
    Square = x * x;
    System.out.println(Square);
    x += x;
    System.out.println("adding x to x to get " + x);
    System.out.println("x * x will now be " + (x*x));
}
```

For N = 50, Prints

```
1
adding x to x to get 2
x * x will now be 4
4
adding x to x to get 4
x * x will now be 16
16
adding x to x to get 8
x * x will now be 64
```